# Agregar elementos a un array y separarlos con punto y coma en Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

mi duda es lo siguiente:
Tengo un array vacío y ese array es añadido con elementos. La separación entre los elementos añadidos es por “,”, que es algo por defecto. Sin embargo, cómo se podría reemplazar esa “,” por un “;” al momento de añadir un nuevo elemento quedando de esta manera.
a = [“a”; “b”; “c”]
Uso javascript.

Como detallé, el resultado que deseo obtener es ["a"; "b"; "c"]

Comment: No se puede, que el separador entre elementos de un array sea la coma es inherente al lenguaje (Javascript en tu caso). ¿Por qué necesitas que sea el punto y coma? Quizá conociendo la razón podamos darte alguna solución alternativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible cambiar la ',' comma por un ';' al menos no en un arreglo, ya que por defecto el lenguaje buscará siempre esa comma, para separar los elementos, y aún si es posible como en el ejemplo que te muestro a continuación, el lenguaje se quejará y te dira que los elementos van separados por ',' y no por ';'.

```
//Arreglo separado por commas
let arreglo = ["A","B","C"];

//El arreglo se convierte a un string
let arrToString = JSON.stringify(arreglo)

//Reemplazamos las commas por punto y comma
arrToString=arrToString.replaceAll(",",";") 

 //Aquí el string del arreglo ya no tiene commas fuerón cambiadas por punto y comma
console.log(arrToString)

//Convertimos de nuevo a arreglo como al inicio con la diferencia de que ya no es comma sino punto y comma
let againArr = JSON.parse(arrToString)

//El lenguaje en si te mostrará un error como "Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or ']' after array element in JSON"
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo aquí:
https://codepen.io/jonath4n/pen/BavYZXj?editors=1012

Sí lo que buscas es separarlos por punto y coma tienes que ingresarlo junto con  en este caso la letra, pero si fueran emails tendrías que agregar el ; al final del email en el string:

Ejemplo:

```
let emails = ["miemail@test.com;","johndoe@mail.com;"];
```

ó un string completo separado por punto y commas:

```
let emails = "miemail@test.com; johndoe@mail.com;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu duda no es clara, pero asumiendo que visualmente quieras ver eso, lo que podés hacer es lo siguiente:

```
let a = ["a","b","c"];
let cadena = "[";

for(let x in a){
    if (x == a.length-1){
        cadena+=a[x]+"]"
    }else{
        cadena+=a[x]+";"
    }
    
}

console.log(cadena);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es inprimir en pantalla o consola el array pero con los elementos separados por coma puedes usar la funcion join

let data = [1,2,3]
console.log(`[${data.join(';')}]`)